# TMP using using-directives

Tags: c++, types, template-meta-programming

Today I played around and tried to achieve template-meta-programming using using-directives.
So far I managed to write simple function calls, but nothing more.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template< int value_ > struct int_type { static constexpr int value = value_; operator int() { return value; } };

template< class lhs, class rhs > using lt = int_type <
    (lhs::value < rhs::value) ? 1 : 0
>;
template< class lhs, class rhs > using plus = int_type <
    lhs::value + rhs::value
>;
template< class val > using mm = int_type <
    val::value - 1
>;
template< class val, template<class> typename func > using apply = func< val >;

int main() {
    using i5 = int_type< 5 >;
    using i3 = int_type< 3 >;
    using x = apply< plus< i5, i3 >, mm >;
    std::cout << x{};
}
```

Is there any way to make recursion in this manner. The following does not work:

```cpp
template< class lhs, class rhs > using times2 = int_type <
    lhs::value * rhs::value
>;
template< class first, class ... rest > using times = times2< first, times< rest...> >;
```

Comment: Without recursion, but with [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) (C++17): `template<class ... args> using times = int_type<(args::value * ...)>;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[temp.alias]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.alias#4) forbids this sort of thing.

> The defining-type-id in an alias template declaration shall not refer to the alias template being declared. The type produced by an alias template specialization shall not directly or indirectly make use of that specialization.

So no, alias templates alone can't be recursive. You'd need something else (like the usual class template and `typename Operation<T1, T2>::result` TMP mechanism) somewhere in the cycle.